# Is it a given or an assumption that all POSIX/SUS signals are a #define?

Tags: c, signals, posix, sus

Signals differ between implementation. There are some nice tables in APUE (Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment), such as "Figure 10.1 UNIX System signals" on page 292 of the 2nd edition.

So let's take the exemplary `SIGWAITING`. Signals appear [in the documentation as `int`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html), but most implementations seem to use a `#define` instead of a `const int`.

However, does the standard stipulate anywhere that one can rely on signals being `#define`d? Or can I assume it based on the fact that, say, virtually every existing implementation uses `#define`. Or is this a bad assumption altogether?

The rationale is this: if I can rely on `#define` being used, I can use `#ifdef` to hide the more exotic signals from implementations that don't use it. For `const int` constant names I am not aware of a similar mechanism that would allow this compile time decision to be made.

Comment: @Duck: they hurt the compiler, because it will simply refuse to compile if it finds an unknown symbol name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the POSIX (2008, 2013) specification for [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_43).  In part, it says:

> The `<signal.h>` header shall define the following macros that are used to refer to the signals that occur in the system. Signals defined here begin with the letters SIG followed by an uppercase letter. The macros shall expand to positive integer constant expressions with type int and distinct values. The value 0 is reserved for use as the null signal (see [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html)). Additional implementation-defined signals may occur in the system.
>
> …
>
> The following signals shall be supported on all implementations…

and this is followed by a table of signal names.  The version you link to is the 2004 edition of the standard, and it is not so explicit about the signal names being macros, but the later version codifies existing practice.

So, to be POSIX conformant, the signal names shall be `#define`'d.

Comment: ... and, to complete the circle, the POSIX requirement for a `#define` is there precisely because lots of existing code wants to use `#ifdef` to test whether signal constants are available.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks, awesome. This was the missing piece. The page I linked merely states: "This header also declares the constants that are used to refer to the signals that occur in the system." and doesn't mention *macros* specifically.

Comment: It's an interesting difference between the standard versions.